# Is it a better way to use an Init() for memory allocation than Constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, constructor

Suppose I have things like:

```
class obj001
{
public:
    obj001() {
        std::cout << "ctor == obj001" << std::endl;
    }

    ~obj001() {
        std::cout << "dtor == obj001" << std::endl;
    }
};

class obj002
{
public:
    obj002() {
        std::cout << "ctor == obj002" << std::endl;
    }

    ~obj002() {
        std::cout << "dtor == obj002" << std::endl;
    }
};

class packet001
{
public:
    packet001(): p01(NULL), p02(NULL) {
        /*p01 = new obj001;
        p02 = new obj002;
        throw "hahaha";*/

        std::cout << "CTOR == PACKET01" << std::endl;
    }

    ~packet001() {
        delete p01;
        delete p02;

        std::cout << "DTOR == PACKET01" << std::endl;
    }

    void init() {
        p01 = new obj001;
        p02 = new obj002;
        throw "hahaha";
    }

    obj001* p01;
    obj002* p02;
};
```

And if I do:

```
try
{       
    packet001 superpack;
    superpack.init();
}
catch(char* type)
{

}
```

Then the `init()` failed, and the Dtor of `superpack` will be called.

But if I put memory allocation inside the Ctor of `superpack`,
(And do not execute `init()`, of course)
then after the Ctor failed, the Dtor will not be called, so `p01` and `p02` are leaked.

So, it it better to use things like `init()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **two phase construction**, ordinary construction followed by an outside call to an `init`function, means that after construction you don't know yet whether you have a valid object at hand. And that means that in any function that gets such an object as argument, you don't know whether the object is valid. This means a lot of extra checking and uncertainty which in turn means bugs and added work, so, a constructor should instead establish a fully functional, valid object.

The set of assumptions that go into the notion of "functional, valid" is called the **class invariant**.

So in other words, more academic phrasing, the job of a constructor is to establish the class invariant, so that it’s known to hold after construction.

Then keeping the object valid in every externally available operation, means that it will continue to be guaranteed valid. Thus no further validity checking is required. This scheme isn’t entirely 100% applicable to all objects (a counter-example is an object representing a file, where any operation might cause the object to become effectively invalid), but mostly it’s a good idea and works well, and where it doesn't work directly, it works for the parts.

So in your constructor you should ensure cleanup by one of the following means:

- Use standard library containers (or 3rd party ones) instead of dealing directly with raw arrays and dynamic allocation.
- Or use sub-objects that each manage just *one* resource. A sub-object can be a data member or a base class. If a data member, it can be **smart pointer**.
- Or in the worst case, use `try`-`catch` for direct cleanup.

It’s also technically possible to use the C idea of checking return values to invoke direct cleanup as necessary. But the list above is in order of decreasing ease and safety. The C style coding is somewhere beyond the bottom of that list.

---

The C++ language creator, Bjarne Stroustrup, has written a little about this very subject, in his appendix [*Appendix E: Standard-Library Exception Safety* appendix to the 3<sup>rd</sup> edition of *The C++ Programming Language*](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe0.html). Just download the PDF, and in your PDF reader search for “init(”. You should land directly a bit into section §E3.5, about *Constructors and Invariants*; do read on through at least section §E.3.5.1 about *Using init() Functions*.

As Bjarne lists there, …

> […] having a separate `init()` function is an opportunity to
>     [1] forget to call `init()` (§10.2.3),
>     [2] forget to test on the success of `init()`,
>     [3] call `init()` more than once,
>     [4] forget that `init()`might throw an exception, and
>     [5] use the object before calling `init()`.

Bjarne’s discussion is, I think, great for a beginner, as is the whole book.

However, be aware that a common reason for two-phase construction, namely to support **derived class specific initialization**, is simply not mentioned at all, not part of Bjarne’s picture here. This is the reason for two-phase initialization in many GUI frameworks. Some C++ GUI frameworks with OK single phase initialization do exist, however, proving that mostly it was all an educational issue – that those early C++ programmers simply did not know about, or could not assume that their library users would understand, C++ RAII.

Comment: Great view! "a constructor should instead establish a fully functional, valid object" is very convincing, I'll avoid tow-phase-construction then.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to avoid these kinds of allocations altogether.  You can put instances directly within a class for many things.  If you really need a pointer, you can use unique_ptr and shared_ptr for automatic memory management.

In your example, this would be fine:

```
struct packet001
{
    obj001 p01;
    obj002 p02;
};
```

If you need them to be pointers:

```
struct packet001
{
    packet001()
      : p01(new obj001),
        p02(new obj002)
    {
    }

    std::unique_ptr<obj001> p01;
    std::unique_ptr<obj002> p02;
};
```

The memory will automatically be freed in the destructor, and deallocations will happen properly if an exception occurs during construction.

Comment: Hi: because in my case, `p01` can be replaced at run-time, so it has to be an pointer.

Comment: shared_ptr is good, but my project is not using it at all, so I am looking for a work-around. So, is `init()` a solution?

Comment: Thanks, I mean my (commercial) project is not using "smart" pointers at all at the moment. But I will try to introduce it to the project if necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you catch all exceptions in Ctor and clean up properly if exceptions arrive inside Ctor?

Comment: Hi: the only exception would be bad_alloc, but I'm not sure if I should catch that one.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two phase construction, or various other means pointed out for in constructor cleanup, in instances where the constructor is likely to fail many a times AND where I want the program to continue to run even after that failure; e.g. trying to construct an object that reads a file, where the file name was provided by the user. There the constructor is likely to fail many a times, e.g. on bad user input.

But bad_alloc - that should be rare for a well designed program. And what exactly are you going to do if the memory allocation fails? Your C++ program is **most likely** doomed at that point of time. Why worry about a memory leak at that point of time? Now you can point out some counter examples where programs can continue to run even after encountering a bad alloc, OR programs which employ *fancy* techniques to avoid bad_allocs, but is your program one of those?

Comment: True! Actually I have no idea what to do if I encounter a bad alloc for my project(actually a commercial project). Maybe just let it crash is the best solution!

Comment: You can have a global handler to 'catch' all errors and at least 'attempt' to report to the user that the program encountered a serious error. And since you are going to do anyways, do away with 2 phase constructors.